# Convert string into list of tuples

Tags: python

I need to convert tuples into an array of strings with those tuples.

So this:

```
(A, "DEFAULT"), (B, "a$"), (C, "aa$"), (D, "(a|b|c)*aab(a|b|c)*")`
```

Should become this.

```
['(A, "DEFAULT")', '(B, "a$")', '(C, "aa$")', '(D, "(a|b|c)*aab(a|b|c)*")']
```

Comment: You say you want to convert strings to tuples, but from your posts it looks like you want the opposite.

Comment: Where are you getting such a string? It looks like someone simply dumped the text-representation of a python `tuple` object into a text file (csv maybe?) and called that serialization.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga reading it from input.txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = '(A, "DEFAULT"), (B, "a$"), (C, "aa$"), (D, "(a|b|c)*aab(a|b|c)*")'
split = string.split('),')
result = []
for i in range(len(split)):
  if i != len(split) - 1:
    text = split[i] + ')'
    result.append(text)
  else:
    result.append(split[i])
```

Got it!